# Angular - Restrict user not to enter more than 5 character using Form control not in HTML

Tags: angular

Type Script

[image]

HTML

[image]

Output

[image]

Could you please help me out from this?

How to restrict a control name "first" not to enter more than 20 characters?

I know how to do it in HTML.

Is it possible to restrict a form control in TS file.

Please help me find out this.

Comment: Instead of posting images of the code, can you add the code directly in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Component HTML File

```
<div>
  <h3>My Restricted Control</h3>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="restrictedInputControl">
</div>
```

Component TS File

```
export class AppComponent {
  restrictedInputControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(5)]);
  allowedCharacters = 'abcdefgh'; // Anything not included in this string will be removed

  constructor() {
    // We subscribe to every change ocurring to this FormControl
    this.restrictedInputControl.valueChanges.subscribe(newInput => {
      // Get the last user input
      const lastEntry = newInput.split('')[newInput.length - 1];

      // Check if the last input character is in allowedCharacters
      if (!this.allowedCharacters.split('').includes(lastEntry)) {

        // If it doesn't exist in allowed ones we Patch the FormControl value with the forbidden character sliced from current value;
        const valueWOLastInput: string = this.restrictedInputControl.value.slice(0, this.restrictedInputControl.value.length - 1);
        this.restrictedInputControl.patchValue(valueWOLastInput);
      }
    });
  }
}
```